# Annotation/Highlight doesn't work in Apple Preview

Tags: preview, screen-capture, image-editing

I have a screenshot. I want to highlight some parts of it. The highlight icon is disabled; the `Tools > Annotate > Highlight Text` is greyed out.

Why? And how can I highlight easily on my screenshot `png` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't highlight text because the format of your screen capture is a bitmap (a set of pixels and not text).

Nonetheless, if the text you wanted to highlight is horizontal enough and not too distorted, you can achieve a nice highlighting effect with `Tools > Annotate > Rectangle`. Then choose a color which isn't frequent inside your image, let's say `Lemon` and decrease the opacity to less than 25 % to be able to see the text through as in this example:
[image]

If your need is important in volume of text to highlight, you will have to use an OCR software to transfom your image into text.